# Which of the following statement(s) are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Define a function :

$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       x+x^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}), \;\; x\ne0\\
       0, \;\; x=0. \\ 
     \end{cases}
$$
Consider the following statements:

(i)$f'(0)$ exists and is equal to $ 1$.

(ii) $f$ is not increasing in any neighborhood of $0$

(iii)$f'(0)$ does not exist.

(iv) $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

Which of the following statement(s) above are correct?

> Solution:

To check the differentiabilty at $0$:

$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{h+h^2\cos(\frac{\pi}{h})}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}1+h\cos(\frac{\pi}{h})=1$ and $\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{-h+h^2\cos(\frac{\pi}{h})}{-h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}1-h\cos(\frac{\pi}{h})=1$

But when $x=0$, we have $f(x)=0$ and so $f'(0)=0$. Hence, $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Now, $f'(x)=1+2x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})+\pi\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$ when $x\ne 0$. So, $f'(1)=1+2(-1)+0=-1$. Hence, $f$ is not increasing on $\mathbb R$.

I want to know how do i check option (ii) and whether the above solution is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) is true. You proved that $f'(0)$ exists and equals $1$ and the concluded somehow that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

(ii) is true and hence (iv) is false. Of course (iii) is false.

To prove that (ii) is true note that $f'(x)=1+2x\cos (\frac {\pi} x)+\pi \sin (\frac {\pi} x)$. From this we see that $f'(\frac  1 n)=1-\frac  2 n (-1)^{n} >0$ for all $n>2$. on the other hand $f'(\frac  2n)<0$ for infinitely many $n$ (In fact whenever $n=4k-1$ for some positive integer $k$). Hence $f$ is not increasing in any interval around $0$.

Comment: It should +$\pi \sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$ in the expression of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @s1mple You are right, I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As $\lim_{x \to +\0}$ cos(pi/x)->1. (edit: I just realized I lazily googled 'cos(pi/0.0000001)' to see where it was going and didn't even think of the situation. The cos part is definitely osscillating.... But it oscillates between 1 and -1, and then is multiplied by x^2 which when close to zero makes it not effect the 'x' part of the equation which dominates around 0 and is only more overbearing the closer to 0 the function gets. I'm going to rewrite this post properly but I can't right now. The idea of cos(pi/x)->1 and of that part not oscillatiing was totaly wrong. But by freak chance it doesn't make any of my analysis wrong, because it is still negligable.) The whole eqation approaching 0+ is (0+*0+^2*1-). The equation is not oscilating as cos(pi/x) gets closer to 1. Until it gets to 1 it stays a little bit smaller. So every part of the formula is a product of 'aproaching 0'*'aproching zero ^2 faster'*'1 but even less'. So if the cos(pi/x) maxes out at one, at most it doesn't change the rest of the formula at all. Since the rest of the formula is approaching 0 it being multiplied by 1 would leave it the same and being multiplied by less than 1 would make it smaller and it is approaching 0, so there is no contradiction with any part reaching infinity mixing with parts reaching 0. It's all parts reaching 0 and a part reaching a constant, with no oscillation.

I've never seen wording of 'in the neighborhood of' but I can only assume it means the obvoius. lim+ or lim- at 0.From the positive direction it definitely approaches 0 and only gets closer to 0 on it's way, so there is no jump or hole, so it is a continuous function. If it wasn't the answer would automatically be no (on the right side) because a jump isn't an increase. Since the behavior is to approach 0 from a positive number on the right side, the answer is no, because it is increasing (edit: i misread the queastoin as asking if it WAS increasing. Really sorry about that)

On the left side, x+x^2+cos(pi/x) swithces. As cos(pi/x) gets close, it is still getting close to acting like 1, so it can be 'ignored' (or set aside until you know if you need to look at it again). As a negative number gets squared it becomes positive, but if it's -1

x+x^2(cos(pi/x)). Here is wher you should double check the cos you set aside isn't doing something funny. You have a super tiny number that is negative, and you think it will stay negative so you are checking that what you add is less than it. So now you can set aside the x and look at the second part and the product. A number with a trillion extra zeros of decimal places and it is being multiplied by something that is at most less than one so that multiplying makes it smaller. You know even thought the second part is positive it is smaller than how already smaller it was just by squaring near zero. (edit: so since the lim(o)- is a negative number, it is increasing on that side as well. I am assuming increasing means the y value goes up from left to right. For a moment I had thought it meant the y value went up around that point. I am way out of practice. But my wits are intact)

If you have to show work, the limits of each part of the equation and a quick blurb about the reasoning gives full marks. Unless you have a special teacher or special course.

It sounds way more complicated, but it is way simpler to just look at and understand what it means when you are reaching the limit. It's easy numbers so you don't need to derive. It seems like that is where you hit a wall and that is why this question is given. So you don't become overly reliant on formulas and become blind to the actual situaions.

If I as you if 1.32452323423 X 10^12 < 5.12387921739172379 X 10^-8 / 4.9283749873274983729 x 10^-7 , understanding how these problems work and behave lets you know the answer without doing all the tedius calculations. If it was a no calculator test you could do the long devision, but the answer can be given without any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

My calculus is certainly slopy right now, but I know this function approches zero from the right from a positive number, so it absolutely is increasing to the right from 0. I saw 'hence f is not increasing in any interval around 0 ' and I am confident that is wrong.

ii) is a true statement.